# Motivo de fechamento escrito errado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

O motivo de fechamento `fora do escopo`>`outro motivo` (último opção) está escrito errado. Tem alguns `r` sobrando (ou sendo puxados :D).

> [image: screenshot]
>
> Notar o "**errrado**"

Comment: É que os tradutores são de Piracicaba :)

Comment: @bfavaretto então ta cerrrto sô. xD

Comment: @bfavaretto esqueceu os porrtuguêses de novo :P

Comment: @JorgeB. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aL9Svopl6bc

Comment: @bfavaretto muito lindo esse sotaque ahahahahah

Comment: @perdeu Prrroblema?

Comment: Ironia o @ **rr** ay postar isso.

Comment: Na época ele **perdeu** a ironia :)

Comment: @bfavaretto seu comentário foi infeliz. Falarrr de Pirrracicaba assim é considerado preconceito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faz parte das strings que não estão no Transifex por virem direto do banco de dados... Mas já foi consertado!